# Plot a function of a binary logarithm with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

How do I plot a function of a binary logarithm with TikZ? Say that I want to plot `f(x) = log_2 x`.

Comment: You should look at the `pgfplots` package (page 33). It's much better than `tikz` for plots and it can use the external program gnuplot!

Comment: @Spike The problem is that I don't find a command for binary logarithms for TikZ or gnuplot. Also you don't need pgfplots to call gnuplot from TikZ.

Comment: Do you need the horizontal axis in semi-log scale? :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `pgfmath` function that you can use directly in TikZ is called `log2`. PGFplots uses the `fpu` library, which doesn't have this function, but you can get the same result by using `ln(x)/ln(2)` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\draw [help lines] (0,-4) grid [step=1] (10,4);
\draw (0,0) -- (10,0);
\draw plot [domain=0.1:10,samples=100] (\x,{log2(\x)});
\draw plot [domain=0.1:10,samples=100] (\x,{log2(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
\begin{axis}[domain=0:10,
  samples=100,
  enlarge x limits=false,
  grid=both,
  no markers,
  axis equal]
\addplot +[thick] {ln(x)/ln(2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: log2]

Comment: I get `! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `log2'.` from the top graph (using log2()). Maybe it's my TikZ version (2008/02/13 v2.00 (rcs-revision 1.27)).

Comment: @N.N. Yes, v. 2.0 is outdated, you should upgrade to the current version 2.1